# ES6 export all values from object

Tags: module, export, ecmascript-6

Say I have a module (`./my-module.js`) that has an object which should be its return value:

```
let values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

// "export values" results in SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

So I can import them like:

```
import {a} from './my-module'           // a === 1
import * as myModule from './my-module' // myModule.a === 1
```

The only way I found is by hard coding the exports:

```
export let a = values.a
export let b = values.b
export let c = values.c
// or:
export let {a, b, c} = values
```

Which is not dynamic.

Is it possible to export all values from an object?

Comment: No, because dynamically computed value cannot be statically exported.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to make the values static in someway. I was thinking about what if you use an `interface { a: number, b: number, c: number }`? Theoretically it should be possible, right?

Comment: @Fleuv `export const {a, b, c} = values` is precisely the syntax to declare that static interface

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Does not seem so. Quote from [ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html):

> You may be wondering – why do we need named exports if we could simply default-export objects (like CommonJS)? The answer is that you can’t enforce a static structure via objects and lose all of the associated advantages (described in the next section).

Comment: Could you use an array if they have name-value pairs?

Answer (score 106):

I can't really recommend this <strike>solution</strike> work-around but it does function. Rather than exporting an object, you use named exports each member. In another file, import the first module's named exports into an object and export that object as default. Also export all the named exports from the first module using `export * from './file1';`

**values/value.js**

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let c = 3;

export {a, b, c};
```

**values/index.js**

```
import * as values from './value';

export default values;
export * from './value';
```

**index.js**

```
import values, {a} from './values';

console.log(values, a); // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} 1
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend this?

Comment: Maybe because the cure is worse than the illness (unless you're writing a publicly-consumable library and you're really picky about how its imported)?

Comment: Yea, that's a good summary. It's a technique I used once in library to ease consumability. I think it'd be better to manage the exports within a single file even though it's more work for the library author. The result is one less module depth for the user.

Comment: I quite like this work-around, but it should be './value' instead of './values' in values/index.js, right?

Comment: @JanPaepke Good catch! I'll fix that up.

Comment: I really don't think this is the answer, since if I already export `{ a, b, c }`, why do I need to export again ? The real question is what if I only have `const obj = { a, b, c }` and can I export obj's all member ? I guess the answer is NO.

Comment: Man, it worked for me. Thanks. You know, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: this does not solve the question asked - how to export every value in an object dynamically - which can't be done. this technique provides a layer of separation between the modules (files) in a package (directory) any consumer of that package (even if part of the same project importing in another dir), freeing the consumer from knowledge of the package's internal file structure and being immune to changes in the package's file structure. it essentially provides a single, clean interface of the package's "public" exports

Answer (score 19):

I just had need to do this for a config file.

```
var config = {
    x: "CHANGE_ME",
    y: "CHANGE_ME",
    z: "CHANGE_ME"
}

export default config;
```

You can do it like this

```
import { default as config } from "./config";

console.log(config.x); // CHANGE_ME
```

This is using Typescript mind you.

Comment: You should be able to do `import config from './config';`

Answer (score 18):

try this ugly but workable solution:

```
// use CommonJS to export all keys
module.exports = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

// import by key
import { a, b, c } from 'commonjs-style-module';
console.log(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 7):

I suggest the following. Let's expect a **module.js**:

```
const values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

export { values }; // you could use default, but I'm specific here
```

and then you can do in an **index.js**:

```
import { values } from "module";

// directly access the object
console.log(values.a); // 1

// object destructuring
const { a, b, c } = values; 
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2
console.log(c); // 3

// selective object destructuring with renaming
const { a:k, c:m } = values;
console.log(k); // 1
console.log(m); // 3

// selective object destructering with renaming and default value
const { a:x, b:y, d:z = 0 } = values;
console.log(x); // 1
console.log(y); // 2
console.log(z); // 0
```

More examples of destructuring objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 7):

Why not just do a named export of the object:

```
let values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
export { values }
```

or

```
export let values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

and then a named import where you need it:

```
import { values } from './my-module'

let foo = values.a
let { a, b, c } = values
```

or

```
import { values as myModule } from './my-module'

let foo = myModule.a
let { a, b, c } = myModule
```

---

can do default export as well:

```
let values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
export default values
```

or

```
export default { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

and then consume it:

```
import whateverIcallIt from './my-Module'

let foo = whateverIcallIt.a
let {a, b, c } = whateverIcallIt
```

---

If you want to export a bunch of individual values, say a bunch of constants, you can:

```
export const a = 1
export const b = 2
//...
```

or even

```
export const a = 1,
             b = 2,
             c = 3,
//...
```

and then import them individually:

```
import { a, b, c } from './my-module'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do lots of stupid thing with javascript. I will leave this quote here from YDKJS book.

[image]

Mentioned page of the book ->

https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=iOc6CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT150&lpg=PT150&dq=JS+engine+cannot+statically+analyze+the+contents+of+plain+object&source=bl&ots=7v8fMUgwhx&sig=dP3BpY7mEvpvfyxO_koWaXczBWI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4qseXyrDdAhUS-6QKHZYTAEQQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=JS%20engine%20cannot%20statically%20analyze%20the%20contents%20of%20plain%20object&f=false

Answer (score 4):

```
export const a = 1;
export const b = 2;
export const c = 3;
```

This will work w/ [Babel transforms](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) today and should take advantage of all the benefits of ES2016 modules whenever that feature actually lands in a browser.

You can also add `export default {a, b, c};` which will allow you to import all the values as an object w/o the `* as`, i.e. `import myModule from 'my-module';`

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export
- http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Answer (score 3):

Every answer requires changing of the import statements.

If you want to be able to use:

```
import {a} from './my-module'           // a === 1
import * as myModule from './my-module' // myModule.a === 1
```

as in the question, and in your `my-module` you have everything that you need to export in one object (which can be useful e.g. if you want to validate the exported values with Joi or JSON Schema) then your `my-module` would have to be either:

```
let values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
let {a, b, c} = values;
export {a, b, c};
```

Or:

```
let values = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
export let {a, b, c} = values;
```

Not pretty, but it compiles to what you need.

See: [Babel example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAbghsCuIDOEC8EDeEYC4IEYAaCAIzwCZiBjPAZggF8AoUSDGYk6htaORJAG4mIAB4AHAPYAnNh1LdBQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Comment: This method is already mentioned in the question (under "hard coded")

Answer (score 2):

Exporting each variable from your variables file. Then importing them with * as  in your other file and exporting the  as a constant from that file will give you a dynamic object with the named exports from the first file being attributes on the object exported from the second.

Variables.js

```
export const var1 = 'first';
export const var2 = 'second':
...
export const varN = 'nth';
```

Other.js

```
import * as vars from './Variables';

export const Variables = vars;
```

Third.js

```
import { Variables } from './Other';

Variables.var2 === 'second'
```

Comment: Can you please also add explanation?