# How to export all keys of an object in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have

```
export const FOODS = {
  FRUITS: {/* ... */},
  RED_MEATS: {/* ...* },
  POULTRY: {/* ...* },
  VEGETALBES: {/* ... */},
}

export const CARNIVORE = {
  RED_MEATS,
  POULTRY,
}
```

Is there a quick way to export all the keys of FOODS without being explicit?

I would like to be able to do something like

```
export const {...} = FOODS;
```

The closest thing I can think would work is

```
export const {FRUITS, RED_MEATS, POULTRY, VEGETABLES} = FOODS;
```

But I have a large number of keys and would like something that requires less lines / less maintance

Comment: `Object.keys(FOODS)`?

Comment: Why not just export `FOODS` as you are now, and let the importers decide what they want from that?

Comment: @Kinduser That returns an array with the keys as strings...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844074/es6-export-all-values-from-object

Comment: You shouldn't have used an object `FOODS` in the first place. You should write a module that exports `FRUITS`, `MEATS` and `VEGETABLES`, and then use `import * as FOODS from …` if you really need them contained in an object.

Comment: @Bergi and I have other exports in the file as well that I wouldn't want to be includeded in foods (see update)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan these exports are already being used I would have to updated 100's of lines to make that change

Comment: @SethMcClaine Then put the foods in a submodule that you can import separately. Basically in the module where you wanted to export them individually anyway.