# Import {functionName} is undefined in list of functions built at runtime

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

A function gathers other functions to export at run time:

```
const list = getFunctions();
```

Where `const list` is an object containing functions:

```
{
 f1: function1,
 f2: function2,
 f3: function3
}
```

Then I export the functions object:

```
export { list };
```

And import one of the functions into another file:

```
import { f1 } from './functionsList';
```

But `f1` is undefined.

Comment: You're adding some unnecessary steps: `export const list = getFunctions();`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm using your suggestion with `export const list`, but it's still undefined. I tried `import { list } from './functionsList'` and it's showing the list of functions. Does that mean the `const` itself is being exported?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes.  [I'd ultimately defer to the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround with module.exports:

`module.exports = list;`

Which worked with `import { f1 }`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704948/665082